# How to set OnClickListener to rotated ImageView?

Tags: android, onclick, rotation, imageview

I need to set an OnClick listener on a rotated rectangle ImageView. I've got problem when setting itafter rotation (angle 45). When i rotated my ImageView, region of the OnClickListener answers in the same place as before rotate :(

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Tween Animations doesn't really "move" the View, [it just alters where it is drawn](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html), i.e. you're going to have to add an AnimationListener and resize (in your case, changing the margins should work)/move the object after the animation has completed for the "physical" location to update.

It's a lot better in Honeycomb / Ice cream sandwich with property animations.